# bash if greater than or equal to error

Tags: bash, if-statement, numerical

With the bash script below I am getting an error;

`line 16: [: : integer expression expected` but I can't figure out why? The error lies in `if [ "$(log_date)" -le "$days_in_ms" ]; then` Can anyone help and explain as BASH if statements confuse me

```
#!/bin/bash

region="eu-west-1"
retention_days="28"
days_in_ms="$(date +%s%3N --date=-"$retention_days"+days)"

log_date () {
  aws logs describe-log-streams --region $region --log-group-name "$groups" | jq -r '.logStreams[].lastEventTimestamp' > /dev/null 2>&1
}
log_name () {
  aws logs describe-log-streams --region $region --log-group-name "$groups" | jq -r '.logStreams[].logStreamName' > /dev/null 2>&1
}

mapfile -t logGroups < <(aws logs describe-log-groups --region $region | jq -r '.logGroups[].logGroupName') > /dev/null 2>&1
for groups in "${logGroups[@]}"; do
    if [ "$(log_date)" -le "$days_in_ms" ]; then
        log_name
     fi
done
```

Comment: Try echoing the variables out and seeing if either of them are non-integer.

Comment: Try to use "[[" and "]]" instead of "[" and "]". See [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash).

Comment: Your `log_date()` function dumps stdout/stderr to `/dev/null`, so how do you expect it to return a number to be tested?  I'd suggest you test some standalone calls to `log_date()` to see what is (not) being returned

Comment: print out what log_date and days_in_ms are. I suspect they aren't not integers.

Comment: BTW, unconditionally redirecting stderr to /dev/null is generally a bad idea -- you're missing out on potentially-useful error messages by doing that.

Comment: Note that this problem is an excellent reason *not* to use `[[` in place of the `[`, since `[[ "" -le 4 ]]` succeeds and generates no error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's Happening

Note the details of the error message:

```
[: : integer expression expected
```

See the blank before the second `:`? That's where the value that `[` is trying to operate on would be, *if there were one*. It's blank, meaning something `[` was told would be a number is not there at all.

To provide an example of how this works:

```
$ [ foo -ge 1 ]
-bash: [: foo: integer expression expected
```

Note that the `foo` is given in the same position where you have a blank. Thus, a blank value is being parsed as a number.

---

#### Why It's Happening

Your `log_date` function does not return any output, because of its `>/dev/null`. Consequently, your code tries to parse the empty string it returns as a number, and (correctly) complains that it's getting an empty string in a position where an integer is expected.

In the future, run `set -x` to enable logging of each command before it's run, or invoke your script with `bash -x yourscript` when debugging, to identify these issues.